# after updating to ubuntu 22.10 ,getting error when installing 'resolvconf'

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you upgrade from? The app you are trying to use is for a method of configuring networking that may not be what Ubuntu 22.10 uses. NetworkManager is a system network service that manages your network devices and connections and attempts to keep network connectivity active when available. It manages Ethernet, WiFi, mobile broadband (WWAN) and PPPoE devices while also providing VPN integration with a variety of different VPN services. The method used in 22.04 and 22.10

Comment: from 22.04 LTS , cloudflare warp

Comment: now I want to install 'resolvconf' to add nameserver

Comment: Do you not also do that with network manager?

Comment: how can I do with network manager?

Comment: This will get you started. https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html

Comment: If you need more info I suggest that you can use the man pages or google. If you get stuck you can ask a new question.

Comment: it is working now ...great

Comment: Great I will make an actuall answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade from a version of Ubuntu not currently using network manager it may appear that the upgraded OS has a broken network.

This is most likely not the case.

All that is needed is to setup network manger configs on the upgraded OS.

Network Manger has many, very many settings.

This reference covers most if not all of them. https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html

There is also the man pages for network manger that are with the OS and of course Google.